# Why can Domeki sometimes see Ghost/Spirit?

Tags: xxxholic

In the early episode of xxxHolic Season 1, we can notice that Domeki not able to see Ghost/Spirit, as a lot of time, Watanuki could see/hear the Ghost/Spirit, but Domeki couldn't.

However, there are few incident where Domeki actually is able to see/hear "Spirit" such as:

- Domeki is able to see/hear Ame Warashi
- Domeki is able to see/hear/Interact/Touch by Zashiki Warashi
- Domeki is able to see/hear/interact/touch Pipe Fox
- Domeki is able to see/hear/interact/touch all the Spirit in Demon Parade (Episode 18)
- Domeki is able to see/hear/interact with the Woman that Watanuki keep meet up with (Episode 22-23)
- Etc

I see a similar trend here.  It seems like those Spirits that Domeki able to see/hear/interact with are "Good" Spirits that without any "Ill-Intent", or actually this is "normal" to every Human to able to see/hear/interact "Good" Spirits because I noticed that Himawari also able to see/hear/interact with Zashiki Warashi and Ame Warashi in the Snow Ball Fight Episode.

So my final question, does Domeki actually have Special Ability to see/hear/interact with Certain Ghosts/Spirits, or Domeki just actually normal, all the Spirits he encountered so far can be also see/hear/interact by other normal human?